# Upper bound for chromatic number: $\chi (G) \le 1 + \max\{ \delta (H):H$ is induced subgraph of $G\} $

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, coloring

I'd love a hint in this problem, because don't know where to start.
For any graph G it follows:
$$\chi (G) \le 1 + \max\{ \delta (H):H \text{ is induced subgraph of } G\} $$
where $\delta (H) = \min \left\{ {{d_H}(x):x \in V\left( G \right)} \right\}$

Comment: Yes, it's the minimum vertex degree I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $d=\max\{\delta(H):H\text{ is induced subgraph of }G\}.$ Assume for a contradiction that $G$ is not $(1+d)$-colorable. Let $H$ be a **minimal** induced subgraph of $G$ which is not $(1+d)$-colorable. Now, every proper subgraph of $H$ is $(1+d)$-colorable. Moreover, $H$ has a vertex $v$ of degree $\le d.$ Can you get a contradiction from that?

Answer (score 1):

The inequality you want to prove is in fact the Szekeres-Wilf theorem with a minor difference that $H$ is a subgraph of $G$ in the theorem, rather than an induced subgraph. But this difference doesn't matter here since the term $\max\{\delta(H)\}$ will be same in both cases.

To be self-complete, the theorem says:

**Szekeres-Wilf Theorem:** If $G$ is a graph, then $\chi(G) \leq 1 + \max_{H\subseteq G}\delta(H)$. Here $H\subseteq G$ means $H$ is a subgraph of $G$.